# Turning the complex number $\frac{-i}{(ix+1)^2}$ in $a + bi$ form

Tags: real-analysis

I don't quite understand the solution of the following problem:

I have the complex number $$\frac{-i}{(ix+1)^2}$$ and I have to present it in the form $a+bi$.

**Solution:**

$$\frac{-i}{(ix+1)^2}=\frac{-i}{(-x^2+2ix+1)}=-i\frac{1-x^2-2ix}{(1-x^2)^2+4x^2}=\frac{-2x}{(x^2+1)^2}+i\frac{x^2-1}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

OK, I understand why $\frac{-i}{(ix+1)^2}=\frac{-i}{(-x^2+2ix+1)}$, but I don't get the rest of the equation. I feel like there's text missing from the solution, or the author has omitted something obvious to him\her which is not obvious to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose thwt you have two complex numbers $z,w$ with $z \ne 0$ and your job is to bring the quotient $\frac{w}{z}$ in $a+bi$ - form. Then you can procced as follows:

$\frac{w}{z}= \frac{w \overline{z}}{z \overline{z}}=\frac{w\overline{z}}{|z|^2}$.

Observe that $|z|^2 $ is real !

Answer (score 1):

Note that we can use the fact that if $z$ is a complex number that can be written as $a+ib$, we have its conjugate $\bar{z}=a-ib$ and that $$z\bar{z}=a^2+b^2$$We can use this fact in the denominator of the second step, noticing that $z= (1-x^2)+i(2x)$ with $\bar{z}=(1-x^2)-i(2x)$ giving us $(1-x^2)^2+4x^2$ in the denominator of the third step.